# OpenCV Build with CMake error

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2013, cmake, opencv3.0

I tried building **OpenCV** using **CMake** with **VS 2013** following  all the following steps given everywhere. Build was successful with a few projects skipped. Then I installed it by building the **INSTALL** project. The thing is, I have got the libraries built for individual tasks but I need **opencv_world300.dll** for use.(I have already used opencv_world300.dll from pre-built libs but its been a year and there have many commits to master GIT ripository and I have encountered bugs in pre-built version, so I need to build from scratch).
There is no project to build opencv_world300.dll in MS VC2013 solution explorer. How do I build it or find it?
As of now, I did some exploring and did this:
While following the steps for building OpenCV binaries from scratch, I found the option to checkmark **WITH_OPENCV_WORLD**. I checked it and hit configure. It configured successfully, then I hit Generate, it is showing error as the following(in red):

```
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenCVModules" ...) includes target "opencv_world" which requires target "zlib" that is not in the export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenCVModules" ...) includes target "opencv_world" which requires target "zlib" that is not in the export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenCVModules" ...) includes target "opencv_world" which requires target "libjpeg" that is not in the export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenCVModules" ...) includes target "opencv_world" which requires target "libwebp" that is not in the export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenCVModules" ...) includes target "opencv_world" which requires target "libpng" that is not in the export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenCVModules" ...) includes target "opencv_world" which requires target "libtiff" that is not in the export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenCVModules" ...) includes target "opencv_world" which requires target "libjasper" that is not in the export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenCVModules" ...) includes target "opencv_world" which requires target "IlmImf" that is not in the export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenCVModules" ...) includes target "opencv_world" which requires target "zlib" that is not in the export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenCVModules" ...) includes target "opencv_world" which requires target "zlib" that is not in the export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenCVModules" ...) includes target "opencv_world" which requires target "libjpeg" that is not in the export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenCVModules" ...) includes target "opencv_world" which requires target "libwebp" that is not in the export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenCVModules" ...) includes target "opencv_world" which requires target "libpng" that is not in the export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenCVModules" ...) includes target "opencv_world" which requires target "libtiff" that is not in the export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenCVModules" ...) includes target "opencv_world" which requires target "libjasper" that is not in the export set.
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "OpenCVModules" ...) includes target "opencv_world" which requires target "IlmImf" that is not in the export set.
Generating done
```

Seeing it, I would estimate that there i dependency problem as opencv_world300 uses all the other modules.

Is anyone knowledgeable on OpenCV or CMake perhaps, to tell me the resolution of this issue. Do I need to make changes in Cmake Root file or the Cache file? I am totally clueless about CMake.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following OpenCV bug report might apply to your situation.

http://code.opencv.org/issues/3448

Comment: I guess, it hasn't been addressed yet and this might be my problem after all.